# FuelPHP - how to return DB result

Tags: php, database, function, return, fuelphp

**Situation:**

I have a controller which contains 2 functions:

- `public function action_all_objects()` - gathers data to show all user objects
- `public function get_address()` - helper function to get address on demand

so in `get_adress` I have DB class query which I execute as `as_object('stdClass')`.

**Case:**

I call `get_address($addr_id)` from `action_all_objects()` and in `get_address` I am trying to return `$result` from the query.

**Problem:**

FuelPHP shows error `"database results are read-only"`

**Question:**

How can I create proper helper function to get address or anything else or what should I modify to get usable result (object preferable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post more code?
After execute() you must use `->as_array()` , for transofrmation object to array.

```
->as_object('stdClass') 
->execute()
->as_array();
```

After this you can parse results like array.

Comment: You only get this error if you try to modify the returned result, there is no need to return as an array. This error is probably generated when you pass the result to the View, which will try to escape the data (which is a modification).